# Why `env` does not find my executable?

Tags: environment-variables, cygwin

I'm trying to use shebang with `/usr/bin/env` form to execute my script under custom interpret. This is how my file looks:

```
$ cat test.rb 
#!/usr/bin/env winruby

print "Input someting: "
puts "Got: #{gets}"
sleep(100)
```

but it fails when executed:

```
$ ./test.rb 
/usr/bin/env: ‘winruby’: No such file or directory
```

and I do not understand why

```
tv185035@WCZTV185035-001 ~
$ winruby --version
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]

tv185035@WCZTV185035-001 ~
$ env winruby --version
env: ‘winruby’: No such file or directory

tv185035@WCZTV185035-001 ~
$ which winruby
/home/tv185035/bin/winruby
```

The `winruby` exists, is in path and is executable. But `env` fails to find it. I took a look at `man env` but it didn't tell me anything useful.

EDIT:

```
$ cat ~/bin/winruby 
#!/usr/bin/bash

winpty /cygdrive/g/WS/progs/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe "$@"
```

Comment: What is the output of `type winruby` ?

Comment: `winruby is hashed (/home/tv185035/bin/winruby)`

Comment: Does `cd; sh -c winruby` succeed when typed to an interactive sgell?

Comment: It does not (`sh: winruby: command not found`), what does that tell me? :)

Comment: Maybe your PATH isn't exported? Try `export PATH`, then try the `env` and `sh -c` commands again.

Comment: 1) didn't help 2) I have `export PATH` in `.bashrc` already 3) I dunno, this is just weird https://pastebin.com/mHisXLct

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

Check that your PATH variable doesn't use "~" to specify the path, as env will not properly resolve it.

So, for example, if you had

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```

Change it to

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

If the output of

`echo 1l|ed test.rb`

ends with `\r$` you have a `<carriage return>` in front of the `<line-feed>`

Lines in unix are line-feed terminated, so `env` looks for the '`winruby\r`' and not '`winruby`'.

edit your script in the unix environment with either `vi` , `ed` or `nano` and remove the '\r' from the end of the line.

Edit:

I can create the same outcome as you, when my PATH is set, but not set to be exported.

```
# PATH is set but not exported
jo@hostname:~/tmp$ winruby --version
running winruby --version
jo@hostname:~/tmp$ env winruby --version
env: winruby: No such file or directory

# print variables starting with PATH
jo@hostname:~/tmp$ set |grep -e ^PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jo/tmp/bin

# print exported variables starting with PATH
jo@hostname:~/tmp$ env | grep -e ^PATH

# Oops ! nothing, so exporting PATH
jo@hostname:~/tmp$ export PATH
jo@hostname:~/tmp$ env | grep -e ^PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jo/tmp/bin

# Final check
jo@hostname:~/tmp$ env winruby --version
running winruby --version
```

Comment: You are correct, I hadn't seen that section. I'll leave this answer standing though, since it might help to look for the <cr><lf> vs <lf> issue. What is `winruby` a windows script to start ruby ? I wonder what that looks like inside.

Comment: I've added `cat ~/bin/winruby` to the question; basically just forward all arguments to windows ruby executable wrapped in winpty

Comment: Does `cat -vet  ~/bin/winruby | head -1` show any stray characters?